# why the function swap function does not work?

Tags: c, function

I have a function `swap()` like below

```
void swap(int x, int y)
{
    int temp;
    temp = x;
    x = y;
    y = temp;
}
```

when  i call it to my main function like this

```
void main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int x,y;
    printf("enter two integer: ");
    scanf("%d %d",&x,&y);
    printf("\nbefore swapping: %d , %d\n",x,y);
    swap(x,y);
    printf("\nafter swapping: %d, %d\n",x,y);
}
```

The function swap() does not work(means not interchange two values).
why this is happen?
can anyone help me to figure out this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your `void swap(int x, int y)` copies the argument, it doesn't use a "reference" to them, contrary to languages like Java (not even sure in Java integers are not passed by value).

Use:

```
void swap(int* x, int* y)
{
    int temp;
    temp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = temp;
}
```

Comment: There is no call by reference in C.

Comment: @Swordfish By reference value

Comment: @NiVeR haha, thanks for making me giggle.

Comment: Haha xD. This can be (and probably is) incredibly tricky for people that meet it for the first time(s).

Comment: Never said that there were references in C.